# How to build the gsl-1.8(GNU Statistical Library) on Win 64bit

Tags: c, static-libraries, gnu

I'm a newbie in compiling GNU libraries(Never did it before).
I have VS 2010 but don't mind downloading other ANSI C Compiler.

If you can assist me in the steps I need to do to run the make file that build the library.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see the win32 port of the gsl got stuck with version 1.8 (current is 1.15), this is quiet old and I'm not sure if a build on win64 will work.

Anyhow if you want to give it a try download the sources from here http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/downlinks/gsl-src-zip.php, unpack everything into a new and empty directory and start by reading src\gsl\1.8\gsl-1.8\VC8\Readme_VC8.htm.

The VC10 compiler should do.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently built, deployed and used the GSL 1.15 for Win 64 with the MinGW gcc of debian, so I can assure you it's possible to build the GSL on Win64. However, I'm absolutely not experienced with VS and can't help you there, sorry. If you can make any use of binaries and a building debian package, please look into [our repository](https://idefix.biozentrum.uni-wuerzburg.de/debian/pool/experimental/main/base/).

Comment: You are doing a cross compile, building the win64 binaries under debian using MinGW?

Comment: @alk: Yes. That's why I can't help the OP much, but know that the whole thing builds.

Comment: Did this work out of the box (at least for gsl) or did you need to patch anything? Btw: Pretty cool approach to get around touching VC ... ;->

Comment: @alk: Worked out of the box. I had to patch the Debian install script in one or two places (like not trying to install .so files), but that has been all.